# get the value echoed by the system() command in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to use an antivirus to scan files uploaded to my website.

```
$esetRes = system('C:\\"Program Files"\\ESET\\"ESET NOD32 Antivirus"\\ecls.exe '.$fileName, $retval);
```

the 'system' command echos a detailed results into my web page, but those results are not returned in the $esetRes variable

> ECLS Command-line scanner, version 8.0.312.0, (C) 1992-2015 ESET,
>   spol. s r.o. Module loader, version 1056 (20150113), build 1082 Module
>   perseus, version 1452 (20150331), build 1682 Module scanner, version
>   11471 (20150414), build 23373 Module archiver, version 1223
>   (20150323), build 1220 Module advheur, version 1154 (20150129), build
>   1120 Module cleaner, version 1107 (20150401), build 1138
>
> Command line: uploads/aXpWo46_700b.jpg
>
> Scan started at:   04/14/15 12:04:48
>
> Scan completed at: 04/14/15 12:04:48 Scan time:         0 sec
>   (0:00:00) Total:             files - 1, objects 1 Infected:
>   files - 0, objects 0 Cleaned:           files - 0, objects 0

is there a way to get those results back and store them in a variable so I can store them in the database?

Comment: Use `exec()` instead `system()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the output by using shell_exec() instead of system()

```
$esetRes = shell_exec('C:\\"Program Files"\\ESET\\"ESET NOD32 Antivirus"\\ecls.exe '.$fileName) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

In http://php.net/manual/es/function.system.php

says:

This is for WINDOWS users. I am running Apache and I have been trying for hours now to capture the output of a command.

I'd tried everything that is written here and then continued searching online with no luck at all. The output of the command was never captured. All I got was an empty array.

Finally, I found a comment in a blog by a certain amazing guy that solved my problems.

Adding the string `2>&1` to the command name finally returned the output!! This works in `exec()` as well as `system()` in PHP since it uses stream redirection to redirect the output to the correct place!

`system("yourCommandName 2>&1",$output) ;`

Answer (score 1):

First! If you are interpolating variables into a shell command use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.escapeshellarg.php) to prevent from shell command injection! You don't want the virus scanner being a backdoor, isn't it?

---

About the problem, it looks like the program outputs the verbose information to `stderr`. You need to redirect it to `stdout` using `2>&1`.

```
$fileNameArg = escapeshellarg($filename);
$esetRes = system('C:\\"Program Files"\\ESET\\"ESET NOD32 Antivirus"\\ecls.exe '. $fileNameArg . ' 2>&1', $retval);
```

Check this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/110930/